# uable to retrieve radio button value from database

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have a method called void showdata() and If I do this...

```
textBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[rno][0].ToString();
comboBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[rno][1].ToString();
```

I am able to retrieve values from database but I am unable to retrieve value from radiobuttons e.g.

```
rBMale.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[rno][3].ToString();
```

by using navigation buttons.

When I say values I mean the green dot that you see from the application not the string value. I have named rBMale as radiobutton.

Does anyone know why that is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear, but it seems that you want to set the [Checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked.aspx) property of the RadioButton.

```
rBMale.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[rno][3]);
```

This property is used to paint the RadioButton with the glyph to represent the value for true or for false

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` property of radio buttons and check boxes is the on screen text that tells the user what the button is (in theory) and has little or nothing to do with its *value*.  What you are probably looking for is the `Checked` property, which is a `bool`.

try something along these lines:

```
rBMale.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[rno][3]);
```